# Refactor procedural Java code to functional code

Tags: java, functional-programming, refactoring

I have the following code in our codebase, and I'm struggling a bit to refactor this in a more functional way, and I was hoping anyone here could help me with this. The idea is to find the address id of person. See code below:

```
public Integer findAddressId(String name) {
    List<Person> persons = getPersons(name);

    Integer addressId = -1;

    for (Person person : persons) {
        List<Address> addresses = findAddresses(person);

        for (Address address : addresses) {
            if (livesAtAddress(person, address)) {
                addressId = address.getId();
            }
        }
    }

    if(addressId > 0 ) {
        return addressId;
    } else {
        throw new RuntimeException("Cannot find address for person " + name);
    }
}
```

These are few helper methods:

```
private boolean livesAtAddress(Person person, Address address) {
    return false;
}

private List<Address> findAddresses(Person person) {
    return null;
}

private List<Person> getPersons(String name) {
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this.

```
public Integer findAddressId(String name) {
    return getPersons(name).stream()
        .flatMap(person -> findAddresses(person).stream()
            .filter(address -> livesAtAddress(person, address)))
        .findFirst()
        .map(address -> address.getId())
        .orElseThrow(() -> new RuntimeException("Cannot find address for person " + name));
}
```

This code will return the ID of the first found address unlike your code returning the last one.

Comment: That seems to be pretty much what I'm looking for. I was struggling with the flatMap/filter combo. Pretty nice, thanks for that!

Answer (score 0):

Using Java 1.8 (since you're going for functional stuff) :

```
public Integer findAddressId(String name) {
  Integer addressID = getPersons(name).stream().reduce(-1, (acc, person)->{
    findAddresses(person).forEach(address->{
      if(livesAtAddress(person, address))
        acc = address.getId();
    });
    return acc;
  });

  if(addressID > 0)
    return addressID;
  else
    throw new RunTimeException("Couldn't find address for person "+name);
}
```

Hope this helps, I am fairly new to Java 8 so there might be a better way than the "forEach if" but this should work properly.